I have deploy SSL certificate in AKS cluster using ingress webapprouting
I have deploy pod, svc and ingress in AKS cluster
Issue is having with ssl certificate is not showing in browser https://dev.perfai.us/
I have created manually ssl certificate and upload in Azure Key Vault after that i update my ingress.yaml file after that i check in browser by hit my URL https://dev.perfai.us/ it show ssl still not activate
Here is my ingress.yaml file
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-webui
  namespace: perfai
  annotations:
#    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    kubernetes.azure.com/tls-cert-keyvault-uri: https://xxxxxxxxxxx/certificates/WebUI-TLS-Certificate
spec:
  ingressClassName: webapprouting.kubernetes.azure.com
  rules: 
  - host: "dev.perfai.us"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
            service:
               name: webui
               port:
                  number: 8080
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dev.perfai.us
    secretName: keyvault-ingress-webui

kubectl get po -n perfai
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
keyvault-ingress-webui-5d897495bc-pswmv   1/1     Running   0          4h31m
learned-models-665d45f9f8-85znk           1/1     Running   0          3h38m
webui-dc9f8f649-cvc6j                     1/1     Running   0          4h33m
webui-dc9f8f649-m6k77                     1/1     Running   0          3h38m
 $ kubectl get ingress -n perfai
NAME            CLASS                                HOSTS           ADDRESS        PORTS     AGE
ingress-webui   webapprouting.kubernetes.azure.com   dev.perfai.us   13.xx.xx.xx   80, 443   4h38m
$ kubectl get secret -n perfai
NAME                     TYPE                DATA   AGE
keyvault-ingress-webui   kubernetes.io/tls   2      4h39m

Here is the SVC
enter image description here
Here is the ingress screenshot
enter image description here
Here is the Azure Key Vault screenshot
enter image description here
And i my subdomain is register on Godaddy and i already created A record in that i added IP address of ingress/LB which got from aks cluster
I dont know where im wrong or what i miss
from above i follow with clear steps and did but dont know where i got wrong or miss
My aim is to setup and application/product in AKS
for that i create a new aks cluster in that i add my 1 service deploy and to add ingress, ssl, hostpath. Dont need to takecare of certificate renew in GCP it will automatically renew and dont know in Azure how i can achieve this.
In GCP i only need to pass Annotations the rest is it will create everything it was very easy but dont know in Azure how to achieve this same scenario in Azure AKS.
annotations:
     ingressClassName: "gce"
     kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: ingress-api-performance
     networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: managed-cert-api-performance


This seems to be a troubleshooting question. As you’ve mentioned that the A record is already set up in GoDaddy, make sure that the DNS A record points to the correct IP address from the Ingress.

already i have setup A record with correct IP

To setup an SSL certificate in AKS ensure your cluster is set up with the App Routing add-on, which will allow you to manage ingress
az aks create \ --resource-group arkorg \ --name cluster1 \ --enable-addons webapp-routing \ --generate-ssh-keys \ --location eastus \ --enable-managed-identity \ --node-count 1


Deploy your application to AKS
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webui
  namespace: perfai
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webui
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webui
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
EOF


kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webui
  namespace: perfai
spec:
  selector:
    app: webui
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: ClusterIP
EOF



Set up/import your ssl cert in the key vault

configure your ingress to use the ssl cert from the key vault
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-webui
  namespace: perfai
  annotations:
    kubernetes.azure.com/tls-cert-keyvault-uri: https://arkokv.vault.azure.net/certificates/WebUI-TLS-Certificate
spec:
  ingressClassName: webapprouting.kubernetes.azure.com
  rules:
  - host: "dev.perfai.us"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: webui
            port:
              number: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dev.perfai.us
    secretName: keyvault-ingress-webui


Make sure your A record for dev.perfai.us (on GoDaddy) points to the external IP of the Ingress. Access your application on https://dev.perfai.us.
Kindly check these two MS documents for further clarity
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/app-routing-dns-ssl
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/app-routing

u have given in details with clearly to understand but i did that correctly like u said but still i didnt get SSL and also SSL which i generate its not working
can u check SSL generate and then upload it in azure key vault
i already did many times

I didn't get you. Do you mean you're not able to generate SSL cert? Do one thing validate the certificate using openssl x509 -in <certificate-file> -text -noout also confirm the format as well. What is it saying?
